# Passing variables between classes in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not terribly good at this modern object coding lark and think I may have misunderstood how this is meant to to work:

This is test.as in my Flash Builder 4.7 project called test

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class test extends Sprite

{
    public var myVar:int = 10;
    public function test() {
        var myTestsub:testsub = new testsub;
    }
   }
}
```

And this is my testsub.as file:

```
package
{
public class testsub
{
    public function testsub()
    {
        trace(myVar);
    }
  }
}
```

Flash Builder tells me that in testsub.as "Possible access of undefined variable myVar" and will not compile.

From my limited, and probably incorrect, understanding, making myVar public in test.as should allow testsub.as to use it. Can anyone explain where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: OOP has been around for 30+ years so it's not that modern but it's just very logical and useful. Classes provide among many things encapsulation which keeps functionality in its own scope and therefore cannot be accessed by other classes by default (default access modifier in AS3 is internal), by using the access modifier 'public' you make data available outside of the class.

Comment: Would you believe that I last coded 25+ years ago and it wasn't in an OOP? Life led me down a different path. Thank you for your information, I think have the direction that public/private etc. work wrong in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wirte your var like this:

```
public class the_var
{
    public function the_var
    {
        public static var my_var:number = 10;
    }
}
```

and call your var in other classes like this:

```
public class the_test
{
    public function the_test
    {
        trace(the_var.my_var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no connections between the classes. They need a link, similar to this solution:

```
public class test extends Sprite
{
    public var myVar:int = 10;
    public function test() {
        var myTestsub:testsub = new testsub(this);
    }
}

public class testsub
{
    public function testsub(otherClass:test)
    {
        trace(otherClass.myVar);
    }
}
```

In test when creating the testsub-class we pass a long a referende to the instance of test. That makes it possible to access public functions & variables on that instance from the other class. (Observer that you need to add test-class as an import inside testsub in order to compile code.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution. More generally I think that I have the OOP model somewhat confused in my mind. I thought that testsub would inherit the variables from test (depending on public/private etc.) when infact it's test that inherits them from testsub (because it has to create an instance of it). Again, thanks for providing clarity.